# New HDD showing CAUTION status

Tags: hard-drive, smart

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [hard drive pending sector count](https://superuser.com/questions/69851/hard-drive-pending-sector-count)

[image]
This drive of mine is less than 2 weeks old. And why am I seeing this CAUTION status? Help please. This is very stressing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purely technical answer:

You are likely seeing the CAUTION state because it found a value at the highlighted part (C5) which was outside its threshold.

Now if you means what does this mean: First read those values mean. Start with [this page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMART_HDD).

Then relax. The raw values column is a mere one.

Comment: And this morning the hard drive crashed. I decided to RMA it. 3 weeks to go. Wow :p

Comment: With a power on count of 54 and 2 weeks since you bought it? That is both harsh and the front of the bathtub curve. (See the "Infant mortality failure" line in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bathtub_curve and Google study on drive failures over time).

Comment: What the hell? Did they ship me a used drive??? I barely used it for 10hours :0

Comment: To be correct, i bought it on 28th of last month

Comment: Your screenshot has a power on count and power on hours. I based the 2 weeks on your "This drive of mine is less than 2 weeks old".

Comment: My bad at the 3 weeks thing. I panicked when the drive began to fail. Its only 1 week old. :)