# Does a non-zero value of reallocated sectors count indicate imminent failure? (in spite of SMART reporting OK)

Tags: hard-drive, smart

I've been told many times that in S.M.A.R.T., the only acceptable value of Reallocated Sectors Count is zero. Any value larger than zero indicates a dying drive; it should be stopped being used, all data should be backed up immediately, and if the drive is still on warranty, this is grounds for demanding a new drive or money return.

What surprises me, however, is the fact that S.M.A.R.T. itself reads "OK" even if as much as 48 sectors are reallocated. Example:

[image]

Does a non-zero value of reallocated sectors indicate a dying drive? If yes, why does SMART report "OK"?

EDIT: 72 bad sectors, OK I'm convinced now :(

--

Judging from: weird sounds; lags during these weird sounds; the recent application crash I'd lean towards the opinion that drive is indeed dying :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I trust a hard drive that has had to reallocate sectors?](https://superuser.com/questions/26842/can-i-trust-a-hard-drive-that-has-had-to-reallocate-sectors)

Comment: @harrymc I am aware of this question however, the supposed dupe cites SMART reporting "Caution" while in my case SMART still reports "OK". For this reason I think the two questions are different

Comment: No, they are still the same. A modern drive has thousands of spare sectors. All is relative.

Comment: SMART will flag it when it starts to run out of spare sectors, all you can do is keep an eye on the smart values over time, that and keep important data backed up.